# the red circle's click event is invoked twice in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, raphael, vml

when I click the red circle, the window will popup a alert once.
It works fine in firefox and chrome, but in ie8, it's popup alerts twice.
How could I fix it?
please see my code in the following:

```
Raphael("world", 1000, 400, function () {
        var r = this;
        r.rect(0, 0, 1000, 400, 0).attr({
                stroke: "none",
                fill: "0-#9bb7cb-#adc8da"
        });
        var click = function(){
                alert(this.type);    
        };

        r.setStart();
        var hue = Math.random();
        for (var country in worldmap.shapes) {
                r.path(worldmap.shapes[country]).attr({stroke: "#ccc6ae", fill: "#f0efeb", "stroke-opacity": 0.25});
        }

        var dot = r.circle(772.9870633333333, 166.90446666666668).attr({
                title: "Point",
                fill: "red", 
                stroke: "#fff", 
                "stroke-width": 2, 
                r: 5
        });
        var world = r.setFinish();
        world.click(click);
});
```

Comment: Try, this... var click = function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
alert(this.type);    
};

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem a few time. Solved it by using a mouse up event instead of a click event. IE sucks.

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to fix this issue, replace the Raphael Set Object with a array Object to push all Rahpael Elements Object, then loop the array to add click event for each Element.
see the following code:

```
    var set = [];
//  r.setStart();
    for (var country in worldmap.shapes) {
        var element = r.path(worldmap.shapes[country]).attr({stroke: "#ccc6ae", fill: "#f0efeb", "stroke-opacity": 0.25});
        set.push(element);
    }

    var dot = r.circle(772.9870633333333, 160.90446666666668 , 5).attr({
            title: "Point",
            fill: "red", 
            stroke: "#fff", 
            "stroke-width": 2
    });

    set.push(dot);
    for(var i = 0; i < set.length; i++){
        var element = set[i];
        element.click(click);
    }
//  var world = r.setFinish();
//  world.click(click);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in Firefox, although what I was doing was completely different.

The way I solved it was to prevent the event from firing twice in too short of an interval.

I would use this function:

```
function rateLimit(func) {
    var lastcall = func.lastcall || 0,
        now = new Date().getTime();
    if( now-lastcall < 250) return false;
    func.lastcall = now;
    return true;
}
```

Then in the function I want to limit from firing too often, I can do this:

```
if( !rateLimit(arguments.callee)) return false;
```

However, you might have a small issue if you are using `alert()`, since that will completely block execution and the second run will still fire. I would strongly suggest using `console.log()` instead of `alert()` to keep track of values, as this will avoid interrupting the flow of the program (especially when you get into asynchronous stuff, you can get real mysteries if you stop things with an `alert`)

Hope this helps!